# Android selector only working on first element

Tags: android, android-selector

I am having a problem with my selector, I have 3 ImageView's in a LinearLayout all having the same selector as background, I have implemented onTouchListeners for all 3 ImageView's, **but** the selector only works on the first ImageView but not on the others... can someone give me a hint what is wrong here?

Selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/theme_color_green_dark" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@color/theme_color_green" />
</selector>
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fragment_captcha_actions"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="100">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_captcha_action_stop"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="33"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_captcha_actions"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_stop"
    android:tint="@android:color/white" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_captcha_action_skip"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="34"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_captcha_actions"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_ff" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_captcha_action_submit"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="33"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_captcha_actions"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem myself...

```
android:clickable="true"
```

was only set on the first element therefore the selector worked only on the first element